# SQL Order By - Conditional not working

Tags: php, mysql

### Overview

I have two tables - one with forum topics, the other with user votes on each topic by ID (values are either 1 or -1).

I have an algorithm that applies to all posts that are younger than 14 days old and an SQL query to retrieve all the posts with their vote total `vote`, their algorithm score total `score`, their ID `id` and the timestamp of when they were posted.

### Query

```
SELECT t.`id`, 
SUM(v.`vote`) AS vote,
(((100 - ( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - t.`timestamp`) / (14*60*60*24) * 100)) * (SUM(v.`vote`) + 10)) + SUM(v.`vote`)) AS score

FROM `community_topics` t

LEFT JOIN `community_votes` v
ON v.`topic_id` = t.`id`

GROUP BY t.`id`

ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN t.`timestamp` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)) 
    THEN score DESC 
    ELSE vote DESC, t.`timestamp` DESC 
END
```

### Question

However, the final line does not work:

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN t.`timestamp` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)) 
    THEN score DESC 
    ELSE vote DESC, t.`timestamp` DESC 
END
```

This is supposed to sort the posts younger than 14 days by their algorithm score, and those older than 14 days by their vote score and then their timestamp.

The error I see is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC, t.`timestamp` END DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 9

Why doesn't this work, or is there a simpler method to achieve this?

Comment: `..THEN score ELSE vote DESC` No need for repeating DESC

Comment: @Mihai that doesn't work as the score will then sort ASC (as default) and I can't specify the `vote` and `timestamp` DESC either?

Comment: DESC will apply to both score and vote,leave the DESC for timestamp.And put the timestaamp outside the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `SORT TYPE` in end of case statement like :

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN t.`timestamp` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)) 
    THEN score
    ELSE vote
    END DESC, 
t.`timestamp` DESC
```